# The connection string 'SGPHARM' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute

Tags: c#

I'm new in .net, and i'm developping a desktop application with C# and postgres database usin npgsql.

Here is my app.config connectionString:

```
<connectionStrings> <add name="SGPHARM" connectionString="host=localhost; port=5432; database=SGPHARM; user id=postgres; password=admin" providerName="Npgsql" /> </connectionStrings>
```

I'm using alsow Code First Approach.
When i'm trying to create a new Product i'm getting the folowing error:

"configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute"

But my providername is specified in the app.config file.
I'm don't now where is the problem.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

The provider name `npgsql` was not specified in the `project_name.exe.config` file.